# HTML5 Boilerplate vs. jQuery Mobile vs. Something else?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, html5boilerplate

What should I use to more *easily* build app-like, beautiful, **PHP/MySQL**-based mobile sites: [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/), [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), or something else?

I don't quite understand the differences between the two, or whether there is something out there that's even better.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pick. There are many tools out there, and most can work together. HTML5BP and jQuery Mobile are fairly different things and can be used together.

Take some classes on [codecademy](http://codecademy.com) and start there.

Once you are familiar with jQuery and html5 essentials, take a look at a framework like [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). These frameworks will give you the "app-like" feel you're looking for.